# could not get database metadata java.sql.SQLException:

Tags: java, hibernate, shared

I am using hibernate sharedFactory for database updation.
When am trying to do one updation am getting the following errors on log:

```
2011-09-01 16:17:50,406 ERROR (org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate:134:execute) - could not get database metadata
java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!

2011-09-01 16:32:05,734 ERROR (org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate:165:execute) - could not complete schema update
java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
```

And the exception is exactly throwing on this line of code..

```
sessionFactoryShard = shardedConfig.buildShardedSessionFactory();
```

Can anyone tell why this error occurs?

Comment: and is your connection string correct? It is simply telling you that it cannot connect to the database or the server is not running!

Comment: yes..dats why it becomes strange..connection string is correct and the updation is also happening..but for each and every updation this error is throwing on the log.

Comment: is there any problem in this question..?or is there any problem in answering this question.???